# Want to improve Career Lattice Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm attempting to improve the following `Graph`:

```
numvertices = 25; xscalingfactor = 100; yscalingfactor = 20;
soctitles = {"Fundraisers", 
"Claims Adjusters, Examiners & Investigators", 
"Purchasing Agents & Buyers, Farm Products", 
"Compliance Officers, Exc. Safety, Agri, Constr & Transp.", 
"Insurance Underwriters", "Appraisers & Assessors of Real Estate", 
"Credit Analysts", 
"Purchasing Agents, Except Farm Products & Trade", 
"Wholesale & Retail Buyers, Except Farm Products", "Loan Officers",
"Cost Estimators", "Meeting & Convention Planners", 
"Compensation, Benefits & Job Analysis Specialists", 
"Logisticians", "Manager Analysts", 
"Tax Examiners, Collectors & Revenue Agents", 
"Human Resources Specialists", "Labor Relations Specialists", 
"Personal Financial Advisors", 
"Market Research Analysts & Marketing Specialists", 
"Accountants & Auditors", "Financial Analysts", 
"Financial Examiners", "Budget Analysts", 
"Training & Development Specialists"};

ef[pts_List, e_] := {Arrowheads[{{0.005, RandomReal[{0.5, 0.7}]}}], 
Arrow[pts]};

vc = ({xscalingfactor, yscalingfactor}*#) & /@ {{143, 53}, {88, 148},
{108, 148}, {128, 148}, {158, 148}, {178, 148}, {198, 148}, {88, 243},
{108, 243}, {128, 243}, {158, 243}, {178, 243}, {198, 243}, {28, 338},
{48, 338}, {68, 338}, {88, 338}, {108, 338}, {128, 338}, {158, 338},
{178, 338}, {198, 338}, {218, 338}, {238, 338}, {258, 338}};

g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 1 -> 6, 1 -> 7, 2 -> 3, 
3 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 3, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 4, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 5, 6 -> 7, 
7 -> 6, 2 -> 8, 2 -> 9, 2 -> 10, 2 -> 11, 2 -> 12, 2 -> 13, 3 -> 8,
3 -> 9, 3 -> 10, 3 -> 11, 3 -> 12, 3 -> 13, 4 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 
4 -> 10, 4 -> 11, 4 -> 12, 4 -> 13, 5 -> 8, 5 -> 9, 5 -> 10, 
5 -> 11, 5 -> 12, 5 -> 13, 6 -> 8, 6 -> 9, 6 -> 10, 6 -> 11, 
6 -> 12, 6 -> 13, 7 -> 8, 7 -> 9, 7 -> 10, 7 -> 11, 7 -> 12, 
7 -> 13, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 8, 9 -> 10, 10 -> 9, 10 -> 11, 11 -> 10, 
11 -> 12, 12 -> 11, 12 -> 13, 13 -> 12, 8 -> 14, 8 -> 15, 8 -> 16, 
8 -> 17, 8 -> 18, 8 -> 19, 8 -> 20, 8 -> 21, 8 -> 22, 8 -> 23, 
8 -> 24, 8 -> 25, 9 -> 14, 9 -> 15, 9 -> 16, 9 -> 17, 9 -> 18, 
9 -> 19, 9 -> 20, 9 -> 21, 9 -> 22, 9 -> 23, 9 -> 24, 9 -> 25, 
10 -> 14, 10 -> 15, 10 -> 16, 10 -> 17, 10 -> 18, 10 -> 19, 
10 -> 20, 10 -> 21, 10 -> 22, 10 -> 23, 10 -> 24, 10 -> 25, 
11 -> 14, 11 -> 15, 11 -> 16, 11 -> 17, 11 -> 18, 11 -> 19, 
11 -> 20, 11 -> 21, 11 -> 22, 11 -> 23, 11 -> 24, 11 -> 25, 
12 -> 14, 12 -> 15, 12 -> 16, 12 -> 17, 12 -> 18, 12 -> 19, 
12 -> 20, 12 -> 21, 12 -> 22, 12 -> 23, 12 -> 24, 12 -> 25, 
13 -> 14, 13 -> 15, 13 -> 16, 13 -> 17, 13 -> 18, 13 -> 19, 
13 -> 20, 13 -> 21, 13 -> 22, 13 -> 23, 13 -> 24, 13 -> 25, 
14 -> 15, 15 -> 14, 15 -> 16, 16 -> 15, 16 -> 17, 17 -> 16, 
17 -> 18, 18 -> 17, 18 -> 19, 19 -> 18, 19 -> 20, 20 -> 19, 
20 -> 21, 21 -> 20, 21 -> 22, 22 -> 21, 22 -> 23, 23 -> 22, 
23 -> 24, 24 -> 23, 24 -> 25, 25 -> 24}, EdgeStyle -> Black, 
VertexShapeFunction -> "ConcaveHexagon", VertexSize -> 0.2, 
VertexLabels -> Table[i -> soctitles[[i]]~Rotate~(-20 \[Degree]),
{i, numvertices}], VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 15], 
GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Top}, 
EdgeShapeFunction -> ef, VertexCoordinates -> vc]
```

I wish to find a way to "wrap" some of the job titles that are long
(but, necessary) so that they won't overlap but, I'm not sure that
this is possible with the available Mathematica tools under `Graph`.
Hence; I'm tilting the job titles to minimize overlapping the arrows
but, unfortunately the titles become misaligned from their
corresponding vertices.  I tried using `Placed` (a tool under
`VertexLabels`) to get the proper alignment but, I couldn't get this
to work.  Any ideas to improve the appearance of this `Graph` will
be most welcome.  Thank you!